# How to check the update date of a remote file in git

Tags: git

So the question is pretty simple, I have a file on a remote repository and I want to get the date it was updated last time, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve the last modification date of a single file in a git repository:

> git log -1 --format="%ad" -- path/to/file

Comment: Good answer - can you put that in backtics so it looks like code?

Comment: Don't forget to fetch

Answer (score 0):

git log -- [file path] shows the changes of a file, work even if the file was deleted.

Or

git log -1 -- [file path] shows which commit deleted a file